# Why some times google map doesn't fit correctly in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

In the following code in Ionic Project, sometimes `map` doesn't fit correctly an center

code:

```
initMap() {
    this.mapInitialised = true;
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    this.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
      this.location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      let mapOptions = {
        center: this.location,
        zoom: 15,
        draggable: true,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        fullscreenControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
      this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds); //# auto - zoom
      this.map.panToBounds(this.bounds);
      console.log(this.location);

      this.PostMarker(this.Postlatlng);
      this.CurrentMarker(this.location);
    });

  }
  CurrentMarker(location){
  console.log(location.lat, location.lng);
  let image = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi_hdpi.png';
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: location,
    icon: image
  });
  this.bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(), location.lng()));
}

  PostMarker(location) {
    console.log(location.lat,location.lng);
    let image = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi_hdpi.png';
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: location,
      icon: image
    });
    this.bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng));
  }
```

**output:**

[image]

**after zooming out:**

[image]

**update**
As you can see in the output map of the screen is pacific ocean while test data point is a place in Tibet and the second point is my current location in Iran. instead of fitting this two point in screen it shows wrong location/area.
This problem mostly happens when two point is so far from each other. In near location Isaw this problem one or two times.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no description of the problem and what was tried to fix it.

Comment: I've updated. Hope description is enough.

Comment: @RSA Good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `minZoom` map option. Otherwise, the screenshot you have posted it how the API (correctly) behaves when you zoom out to 0.

For example:

```
new google.maps.Map(element,{minZoom:3});
```